# How to start off a project plan documentation for research oriented projects?

Tags: ms-project, documentation, small-projects, ms-project-2007

I have planned all the tasks using MS Project 2007. I used shots of Gantt chart, Network diagram and critical path.

Can the project documentation plan have the following contents?

- Project background.
- Objectives.
- Scope.
- Methodologies.
- Core functions such as cost, quality, scope and time

Are these enough for a proper project plan documentation?

The nature of the project is research based and consists of only one working resource. No project team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some very simple questions you have to ask before you start, but it looks like you've got them (almost) all covered -

What is my project, why am I doing it, what do I hope to accomplish, what resources do I have available, what are my constraints, what are the risks, how do I plan to approach and execute the project, etc.?

Make sure the methodology includes some way to measure progress against plan.

You are missing one that I can see, and it's the most important -  how will I know when I'm done and if I was successful? Define your success criteria BEFORE you start. Is it a particular grade, validation of a hypothesis, just completing the assignment?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have understood what to include.

Answer (score 2):

One of the characteristics of a successful project is tailoring the project management methodology to the project's criticality and complexity. So don't ask "Do I have enough?", ask "Do I have what I need?".

To figure out if you have what you need where you are the only team member, talk to the end customer(s)/user(s) and find out what is important to them. Get them to prioritize time/cost/scope/quality so that you have an idea of what trade-offs to make in your plan documentation and ongoing reporting. Have them tell you the level of detail they need. Then balance their requirements off with what you can deliver, draft what you think will work and get their buy-in.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand what you mean. The point is that this is a college assignment. Therefore, I need to know the proper structure of the project plan.

Comment: If this is a college assignment in the sense that delivery of a project plan is part of your assignment then you should consult your professor (the end customer) and find out from him/her what is required.  If this is a college assignment in the sense that you have been asked to define what the "proper" structure of a project plan I hope asking PMSE isn't substituting for doing your own study, if it is you aren't going to get value for money spent on your education in the long run.

Comment: My teacher does not provide proper structure of the project plan. So I did some research. And I just wanted to confirm if that was okay for documenting.